# ChartPlotter memory increase when I draw the chart and never decrease

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, mvvm, garbage-collection

I draw chart with DynamicDataDisplay.ChartPlotter and each time I redraw the chart memory increase. So when I have redraw 200 times my chart memory of my app increase to 200mo in memory.

I tried to GC.Collect() manually but nothing change.

```
    private ChartPlotter _courbeChartPlotter;
    public ChartPlotter CourbeChartPlotter
    {
        get { return _courbeChartPlotter; }
        set
        {
            _courbeChartPlotter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private static ListPointD3Cs _listeX = new ListPointD3Cs { new Point(0, 0) };
    private static EnumerableDataSource<Point> dsX = new EnumerableDataSource<Point>(_listeX);
    private int nbPoint = 0;

    public void TakeMeasureTest()
    {
        nbPoint++;
        _listeX.Add(new Point(nbPoint, GetRandomNumber(-1, 1)));
        InitDotsCourbe(out dsX);
        TraceCourbe(dsX);
    }

    public void InitDotsCourbe(out EnumerableDataSource<Point> dsX)
    {
        dsX = new EnumerableDataSource<Point>(_listeX);
        dsX.SetXMapping(x => x.X);
        dsX.SetYMapping(y => y.Y);
    }


    public ChartPlotter TraceCourbe(EnumerableDataSource<Point> dsX)
    {
        CourbeChartPlotter = new ChartPlotter();
        ViewPortAxesRangeRestriction restr = new ViewPortAxesRangeRestriction
        {
            XRange = new DisplayRange(0, nbPoint + 1),
            YRange = new DisplayRange(-2, 2)
        };
        CourbeChartPlotter.Viewport.Restrictions.Add(restr);
        CourbeChartPlotter.AddLineGraph(dsX, Colors.Red, 2, "X");
        return CourbeChartPlotter;
    }
```

I want memory not increase each time I redraw the chart or at least when I `GC.Collect()` after all Measure retrieve a normal memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're redrawing the chart by repeatedly calling `TraceCourbe` method, and reassigning `CourbeChartPlotter` property, then displaying that. In that case, you probably have a memory leak because something (for example another property, control or an event subscriber) is holding a reference to your `ChartPlotter` control even after it is reassigned and theoretically removed (your case may be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927390/wpf-memory-leak-with-custom-control)).

You can reassign the chart's data source instead, as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142173/dynamicdatadisplay-chartplotter-remove-all-plots).